# TSQL Rolling Date for Every Thursday at 4:00pm

Tags: t-sql, date, datetime, getdate

I would like to create a Select Statement which uses a Rolling Date on Every Thursday at 4:00pm.

We are working on a project where we are using informz as our Web Application to send email blasts to our New Members.  I would like to create a Select Statement that pulls New Members by their Start_Date every Thursday at 4:00pm starting from June 1st, 2013.

The twist in this Select Statement is that I don't want to have a Member get the same email multiple times.  Ideally I only want them to receive the email once.  Originally we only sent out one email.  Now, because of length we have created three one page emails in a series.  We would like to make sure that each new member gets each of the three emails one week apart on a given Thursday at 4:00pm.  After that we would need to roll to the next New Member the following week and repeat the process.  I would like to make sure that each new member receives only the three emails in the series in order and not be repeated.  For example if we number the emails (email_1, email_2, email_3), I would like to make sure the New Member doesn't receive email_1 multiple times.  Does this make sense?

Feel free to reply if you have any questions, as I realize this is somewhat confusing.

Here is what I have so far.

```
SELECT MEMBER_ID, EMAIL, START_DATE
FROM DBO.MEMBER_TABLE
WHERE START_DATE >= '20130601'
ORDER BY START_DATE
```

Here is the software I am using:

- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 9.0
- Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools 2005
- Microsofot Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.1.76
- Operating System 6.1
- Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise (x64)

Comment: Create some sort of counter/flag that records the user ID and current email number. Every week, pick up everyone with "3", send email #3, delete/flag those rows as complete. Pick up #2, send email #2, increment those to #3. Populate new/pick up #1, increment those to #2. There are definitely other ways, but this is one quick way to handle. Ideally - store in a separate table: UserID, Email#, DateSent. Pick up those who haven't been sent #1 for this date, pick up those who were sent #1 last week - send them #2, etc. Several ways to handle - your choice.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Much Appreciated.  I used your suggestion and now the email series are being distributed correctly.  I thought I would have a few more replies, but I thank you for your time and assistance.  Cheers!

Comment: Glad I could give you some assistance and that you have a solution working for you.